# Can a gold badge holder nominate/vote to close a question as a duplicate?

Tags: support, moderators, badges, exact-duplicates

I recently earned the gold badge for Magic: The Gathernig (yay), and that means that now if I mark a question as a duplicate, it is instantly closed. This is a fun new power that I promise not to abuse.

However, sometimes I see a question that I think could be a duplicate, but I’m not sure. Previously, I would have simply marked it as a duplicate, because that would just leave a comment saying “possible duplicate of”, and then other users could come along and decide if I’m correct or not. Now, I don’t want to someone that unless I’m completely sure.

So.. is it possible for me to still vote to close, rather than actually close?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, once you have this power you cannot choose not to use it. Often, if I'm not entirely sure, I'll wait for two or three other people to vote before voting myself. That way, even though my vote is binding, it also requires at least some agreement with others. If nobody is voting to close the question, you can write the comment manually to hint to others to start voting to close.